# byte array has whitespace that can't be removed

Tags: c#, .net-core, service-broker

I have a Service Broker Queue in the database that I'm trying to get the message body from.  The result has has unnecessary whitespace, which I can't remove no matter what I try.   I simply want to collapse everything and remove all extra whitespace.  I've tried Regex, trimming, replace, etc.

Original Data in Queue:

`0x31002C0020003200`

Message Reciever:

```
public string RecieveMessage()
    {
        string message = string.Empty;
        byte[] binaryString = new byte[100];            

        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();

            var sql = "RECEIVE TOP(1) message_body FROM [dbo].[Queue]";
            var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            try
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    binaryString = (byte[])reader[0];
                }

                message = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(binaryString).Trim('\0');
            }
            catch (SqlException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                reader.Close();
                conn.Close();
            }
        }

        return message;
    }
```

Sample Output of `Console.WriteLine(message);`

2 3 5 6 5 3, J o h n  D o e   &   A s s o c i a t e s

Comment: Wrong encoding? Try `Encoding.Unicode.GetString` instead of `UTF8`

Comment: Are you sure your output to console supports the UTF8 string?  Also, are you sure that those spaces are indeed spaces and not some other character?  I'd double check the exact bytes in your output array to verify.

Comment: @JonathonChase ```Unicode``` did the trick. Good catch, and I can't believe I didn't try that before posting.  I Had tried a few versions of UTF and ASCII as my encoding and thought it must have been something else instead.  Thank you!  If you'd like to post a full answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to read unicode/utf16 as utf8, which will end up with what can look like spaces, but is actually null characters.

You can use the unicode encoding instead, which should get you the desired result.

```
message = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(binaryString);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  byte[] data = new byte[1024];
   clientSocket.Receive(data);
       
 string returndata = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, data.Length);
 returndata = returndata.Trim('\0');
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.